# Raise validation error in inline field Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that contains a *TabularInline*, and I want to raise a validation error when a condition is not valid.
My parent model:

```
@admin.register(Even)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'title']
    list_display_links = ['id', 'title]
    inlines = [EventSpecialPriceInline]
```

And my TabularInline:

```
class EventSpecialPriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = EventSpecialPrice
    extra = 0
    can_delete = True
```

The error I want to raise is when a price of a row is negative `EventSpecialPrice.price < 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `BaseInlineFormSet` and used `form.clean`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class EventSpecialPriceInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(EventSpecialPriceInlineFormSet, self).clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False):
                if form.cleaned_data.get('price') < 0:
                    raise ValidationError('Price should be positive')
```

And in my `TabularInline` I've defined a `formset`:

```
class EventSpecialPriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = EventSpecialPrice
    formset = EventSpecialPriceInlineFormSet
    extra = 0
    can_delete = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`MinValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) for your model field

```
class EventSpecialPrice(models.Model)
    price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```