# Django TabularInline raise ValidationError on a specific row

Tags: django, django-admin

before posting the question here I have checked [Raise validation error in inline field Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535051/raise-validation-error-in-inline-field-django).

But this still does not answer my question, because the error thrown is in the form but not on the exact row. In MyModel.clean function if I raise Validation error I can specify the field which is bad. But how can I raise an error on the bad row of a TabularInline?

```
class MyBaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(MyBaseFormSet, self).clean()
        for index, form in enumerate(self.forms):
            if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False):
                raise ValidationError('test')


class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    formset = MyBaseFormSet
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same case.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up throwing a general error